# Cannot POST / Facebook Tab issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, tabs

I am developing a website using React.js and Node.js. The problem comes when I want to create a custom Facebook tab with my page I get this error:

```
Cannot POST /
```

To implement the Facebook tab I've followed these steps:

1. I've created a facebook page.
2. Registered as a facebook
       [developer](https://developers.facebook.com/).
3. Created an application.
4. Selected a platform for the
       application (Facebook Tab).
5. Added the URL of the website I want within the Facebook Tab.
6. Copied
       this URL granted by Facebook:

   https: //www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?
     app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
     &redirect_uri=YOUR_URL

Where I have replaced YOUR_APP_ID and YOUR_URL by mine, and accepted to install the new custom tab within my Facebook page.

When I enter my page, my new tab appears but instead of displaying the content of the website it displays the previous error.

Here's the [source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs) where I've got these steps.

Since I am the Front-end developer of the project, I don't know if the issue comes from the server side or I am doing something wrong.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Page tab apps are loaded into the iframe via an initial POST request, so whatever page tab URL you specified in your app settings must handle a POST request correctly - yours apparently doesn’t. So go check the server configuration in that regard.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll check it. :)